# compare current row date with the previous row date and update the row

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to compare current row timestamp with the previous row timestamp, if the current row timestamp is greater than the previous row timestamp , then I have to update the no_of_students column.

| time | no_of_students |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-08-24 19:00:00 | 100 |
| 2021-08-24 20:00:00 | 123 |

below is the query.

```
SELECT *
,CASE WHEN "time" < (SELECT MIN(time) FROM abc where time < abc.time ) 
      THEN update no_of_students 
      
 END 
FROM abc
```

I am getting error in comparing the timestamp

Comment: What error exaclty?

Comment: Its not returning anything

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is not clear.  Why do you have an `update` in a `select`?

Comment: I have provided the desired result in the table. As I mentioned in the question itself that if the current timestamp is greater than previous timestamp then I have to update the no_of_students

Comment: Since you reference the same table twice, Oracle have no chance to understand, what colum is of what table. Can **you** guess: `where time < abc.time`? But if I will write: `where abc.time > time`? Are they identical or not?

Comment: Also regardless of the mess in table names `"time" < (SELECT MIN(time) FROM abc where time < abc.time )` is always false, because previous row obviously cannot have timestamp above the current row (that's why you call it previous).

Answer (score 0):

This will omit the earliest timestamp.  I'm not sure what your business rules are in terms of how many timestamps there can be for a given key, but given that your example is just 2 rows, this will work for your example.

More details on the LAG function here: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-lag-function-overview-and-examples/

```
DECLARE   @student TABLE
  (
       timeupdate DATETIME,
       no_of_students  INT
    )
INSERT INTO @student VALUES ('2021-08-24 19:00:00', 100)
INSERT INTO @student VALUES ('2021-08-24 20:00:00', 123)

SELECT * FROM   @student;


WITH CTE_StudentSorted AS(
SELECT * , 
Lag(timeupdate, 1) OVER(
       ORDER BY timeupdate ASC) as PriorTimeUpdate
FROM @student
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE_StudentSorted
WHERE PriorTimeUpdate IS NOT NULL
```